# gitolite can not limit user to access branch

Tags: gitolite

I create a new branch of a repository, set permissions on the branch, and only allow a certain user to access, the result is that either the user can access all branches(RW dev = user2), or all branches cannot access (- master = user2), please help me and  points to the maze. . .  the repository can be set to only access and modify a certain branch

Below is my config：

```
@users  =  user2

repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   git1

repo testing
    RW+ master   =   git1

repo repo2
    -   master              =   @users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the meaning of access: Gitolite cannot restrict *read* access (if you can see a repository, you see/clone/pull all of the repository)

It can restrict *write* access (`git push`)

You could use a combination of [separate repositories and partial copies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31921597/6309), for selective read control for branches.
See an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389067/6309).

You can also [restrict Gitolite VREF restrictions to only one branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26276739/6309)